# WPF - Image 'is not part of the project or its Build Action is not set to Resource'

Tags: wpf, image, resources, imagesource, buildaction

I have a project which requires an image in the window.  This is a static image and i added through 'Add>Existing Item'. It exists in the root of the project.

I reference the image in a test page like so -

```
<Page x:Class="Critter.Pages.Test"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="Test">
      <Image Source="bug.png"/>
</Page>
```

Problem is I get a message saying it can't be found or it's build action isn't resource but it DOES exist and it's build action IS resource.  If i create a new application and just throw it on a window then it works fine.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is the image in a sub folder?

Comment: Nope.  the image is in the project root.

Comment: is the build action set to Resource or Embedded Resource ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try doing a full rebuild, or delete the build files and then build the file.

Visual Studio doesn't always pick up changes to resources, and it can be a pain to get it recompile.

Also try using a full URI as that helped me when I had the same problem. Something like

```
pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/bug.png
```

Comment: Thanks dude.  that worked a treat!  Still don't really get those Pack URIs but the full rebuild did the trick.

Answer (score 26):

→ Right click the image file
→ Click property
→ Select Build Action to Resource 
→ Clean and Build solution 
→ Run the Solution

You will get the all.

Comment: Clean and Build for the win!  Took me two or three attempts to realize that the clean action was the only way to get VS to pick up the new resources.

Comment: I was banging my head on the keyboard a few hours, until found your comment. Guess what, clean & build worked like a charm. Thanks a lot, +1 ;)

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution didn't fix it so I restarted visual studio and it did. Here's hoping Visual 2010 fixes this issue and the many others that plauge wpf in Visual 2008.

Answer (score 13):

Try starting the path to your image with a "/":

```
<Image Source="/bug.png"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution to your question

```
<Image Source="/WpfApplication4;component/images/sky.jpg" />
```

"component" is not a folder!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, or at least the current beta doesn't. I found this page while looking into exactly the same problem. Rebuild/clean did nothing. After closing down and reloading the solution the file magically became compatible again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same issue but restarting VS2008 or cleaning and rebuilding the project did not work for me. In the end, the below steps did the trick.

- In Windows Explorer copy the Image into your project resource folder. Example: MyProject\Resources\
- From within Visual Studio right click on the Resources and select "Add > Existing item" and select the image which you have just copied in
- From within the form XAML set the image source as: `"Source="Resources/MyImage.ico"` (my image was saved as icon (.ico) file, but this approach should work for any image type

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Example of async load, another option. Example clip.mp4 is in the web project root.

```
void Landing_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Load video async

    Uri pageUri = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri;
    Uri videoUri = new UriBuilder(pageUri.Scheme, pageUri.Host, pageUri.Port, "clip.mp4").Uri;           

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(videoUri);
}

void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] VideoBuffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
    e.Result.Read(VideoBuffer, 0, (int)e.Result.Length);
    MemoryStream videoStream = new MemoryStream(VideoBuffer);
    ContentVideo.SetSource(videoStream);
    ContentVideo.Stop();
    ContentVideo.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After I deleted a `someStyle.xaml` file that I wasn't really using from the solution explorer. 
Then I restored the file, but no change happened. Cleaning and rebuilding the project did not help.

Simply deleting the corresponding row:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="someStyle.xaml"/>
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but my issues was a simple NOOB mistake.

When I added my .ico files to "My Project / Resources", VS made a sub folder named Resources and I was trying to use;

```
<Window Icon="icons1.ico">
```

when I should have been using;

```
<Window Icon="Resources/icons1.ico">
```

... don't judge, I started using WPF 1 week ago :)