# How to make an image resource part of the program in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I'm making a C# WPF application on Visual Studio 2013. My application has an image in it called `mainImage`.
I made all the images I need in my program to be a `Resource`. and then I was changing the image in my application with a code like this :

```
mainImage.Source = myWindow.FindResource("image") as BitmapImage;
```

The problem is that when I take my .exe and try to run it without the whole project, It gives an exception because it can't find the image.
I want my images to be something like "part of the application", so that wherever I run my application (even if I run it separately from the Visual Studio project), I want the images to show up. Can any one help me with that?

Comment: You need to make sure the image is embedded correctly in the assembly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638845/wpf-image-is-not-part-of-the-project-or-its-build-action-is-not-set-to-resour?rq=1

Comment: This Microsoft article explains how to make and use embedded resources. Embedded resources are compiled into the assembly. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292